# Cannot get an asynchronous response with reasteasy

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, comet, resteasy

Despite of many researches on the web, I can't find any solution of my problem. 
I'd like to call a service from the GUI. The service (a Rest method) launches an asynchronous treatment, with a thread. I want the service to give immediately a response to the GUI, so that the GUI is not blocked. At the end of the thread, the service should give a second response, indicating the GUI that the treatment is completed.

What I want to do seems to correspond to the asynchronous HTTP part of Reasteasy. So, I've tried this code (I let only the important parts for my problem) :

```
@PUT
@Path("/duplicate/1")
public void duplicate(  UcModel uc,
                                final @Suspend(TIMEOUT_ASYNCHRONOUS_DUPLICATION) AsynchronousResponse response) throws BusinessException {


        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

                Response jaxrs = Response.ok(result).build();
                response.setResponse(jaxrs);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

In my web.xml, I've put this code :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

The problem is : the web service doesn't give a response immediately. It gives a response only at the end of the thread, and the GUI is blocked.
By looking at the code, I even don't understand how the service could give a response immediately with a "void" result.

For information : the call of the web service is made in ExtJS, a Javascript framework. It does an Ajax request.

It would be great if someone could help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Cedric

Answer (score 5):

You should use two different webservices to solve this issue.

The `AsynchronousResponse` is mainly for helping the server thread pool performance, not for the client side.

The server has a limited number of threads in thread pool which can serve a client's request, and with the help of `AsynchronousResponse` you can put the time consuming jobs in a background thread.

The client side will have to wait for the async process to complete or timeout. only after that will the response be committed, so for the client it will take almost the same time to complete the request.

Other option is to trying out the `ChunkedOutput` java class which can be found [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ChunkedOutput.java).

This is for sending messages in "typed" chunks. Useful for long running processes, which needs to produce partial responses.

An example:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    public ChunkedOutput getTestResponse() {
        final ChunkedOutput chunkedOutputs = new ChunkedOutput(String.class); 
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {                   
                    while (hasNextValue()) {                         
                         chunkedOutputs.write(getNextLongRunningOperationValue());
                    }                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    (...)
                } finally {
                    chunkedOutputs.close();                        
                }
            }
        }.start(); 
        //the chunkedOutputs will be probably returned even before a first value is written by the new thread
        return chunkedOutputs;
    }   

    private boolean hasNextValue() {
        (...)
    }

    private String getNextLongRunningOperationValue() {
        (...) //this takes a lot of time, so it's time for a coffee :)        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I won't have enough time to try this solution, because I am leaving my project today. So, my workaround will be to remove totally the asynchronous part of my method, and ensure that the client won't be blocked by the processing request. I give your reply to my colleagues, maybe someone will have some time one day to look at it and try a Comet solution

Comment: okay, good luck and please don't forget to vote if the answer was useful for you

Comment: I've tried to vote, but I am a beginner in this forum, so I don't have enough reputation to vote